# C# External Array of Functions

Tags: c#, arrays, function, external

Okay so it's about my project yet again. I have client and server. They communicate between each other and packets have following structure [OP CODE] [LENGTH] [DATA]

Now on server-side I wanna load function code for each OPcode from external .cs file.

So when compiled it will look like this

```
- OPCODES
-- OPCODE1.cs
-- OPCODE2.cs
-- OPCODE3.cs
-- OPCODE4.cs
OPCODES.cfg (has list of all op codes and location for function code)
MyProgram.exe
```

How would I do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Dictionary (assuming that the opcode is an integer

```
        Dictionary<int, Action> actions = new Dictionary<int, Action>();
        actions[7] = () => Console.WriteLine("hello World");
```

to execute opcode "7" you can do

```
        actions[7]();
```

if you want it more robust:

```
        Action action;
        if (actions.TryGetValue(7, out action))
            action();
        // else illegal opcode
```

If you want to load the actions Dictionary from a file it is a bit more complicated
You can call the static method `ConsoleApplicationTest.Program.MyMethod()` via a Dictionary like this

```
namespace ConsoleApplicationTest
{
public class Program
{
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyMethod called");
    }
 } 
 }
```

The Dictonary can look like this

```
        Dictionary<int, MethodInfo> dynamicActions = new Dictionary<int, MethodInfo>();

        dynamicActions[7] = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("ConsoleApplicationTest.Program").GetMethod("MyMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

and the method will be called like this

```
        MethodInfo method;
        if (dynamicActions.TryGetValue(7, out method))
            method.Invoke(null, new object[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use case switch to signal that some packet received.

```
switch(packet.OpCode)
{
   case 1:
   OnHelloPacket();
   break;
   case 2:
   OnInfoPaket();
   break;
   //etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for something much more dynamic than a simple enum or dictionary of actions. You mention in your question that "OPCODES.cfg (has list of all op codes and location for function code)". Does this imply that the opcode functions will not necessarily be compiled with the main server application?

If that's the case you'll likely be looking at some kind of plugin architecture, so you can add and remove opcode functions whenever you like. I'd recommend [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) as a good starting point.